# Randomize destination port for *every* packet with iptables

Tags: linux, iptables

There is a program at server side listens on port 3333, and a dedicated client box which sends and receives packet to the server, I'd like to setup a set of iptables rules, make *every* packet in-the-air with randomized port number.

Here is what I've done:

```
####Client side
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT --dst server.ip.addr -p udp --dport 3333 -j DNAT --to-destination :10000-19999 --random

####Server side
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --dst server.ip.addr -p udp --match multiport --dport 10000:19999 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3333
```

Which basically works, but DNAT will only randomize the 1st packet for the "connection", following packets just use the port number saved in connection state table, and will not change while the "connection" exists.

Then I tried to disable connection tracking with:

```
####Client side
iptables -t raw -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 3333 -j NOTRACK
```

Now server and client cannot communicate, tcpdump shows nothing on the server box, I guess DNAT may not work without connection tracking.

Also I tried some other combinations but no of them worked. There is no target except SNAT/DNAT can modify ports.

Just want to know if what I want is possible, or I was wrong since the beginning.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here. Source port randomisation happens by default, it is part of how TCP/IP communication works. The destination port however has to stay 'real' since the destination is only listening on that given port. It is also correct that the first packet dictates the random source port which the rest of the IP stream uses. Randomising the source port for every packet would likely break the stream and somehow seems pointless?

Comment: @tomstephens89 not the source port, but the destination port is what I want to randomize. I also setup some iptables rules at server side, redirect a port range to the "real" listening port, theoretically it should not break anything, only obfuscate packets on the internet, make connection-based-DPI much harder.

Comment: I am confused how you think a packet with an invalid destination is actually going to be successfully delivered to anyone.

Comment: @Zoredache, the destination address remains valid, only port gets randomized, I mentioned there are some iptables rules on the server box, which change randomized port back to real one.

Comment: @Zoredache, actually I made it partly worked, the dest port is randomized, the problem is it is not randomized *enough*.

Comment: @windoze this looks like something better handled by the application layer in conjunction with encryption, so that the client can tell the server what port it will send to next, or vice versa, the server can tell the client what port to use next (much like FTP), but anyone listening won't know what port is next if encrypted.  In this case, the server is just listening to all ports and deep-inspection will still see the traffic, ableit harder to reassemble the flow.  I should add that linux sometimes adds an ident field, so unless you have TSO enabled, DPI may still be able to reassemble.

Comment: @Aaron, what you said is something like frequency hopping, the problem with the idea is server has to listen a lot of ports while only very few are actually in use, or it must have a strong loss-recovery protocol as client can easily lost track of which port should it talk to, besides, it has to be written from the scratch, which is quite a big effort...

Comment: @windoze I agree with everything you said.  I of all people like to use something simple to accomplish such tasks; but in this one case, I do not believe you will get more randomized than you already have.  If someone provides a working solution, I would be curious to see it as well.  Good luck!

Comment: This question has piqued my interest.  Have you done any of your testing outside of a lab (i.e. local) environment?  Randomizing the ports in the stream certainly has the potential to confound DPI . . . but it could equally confound any number of load balancers, firewalls, routers or other elements in the path between your source and destination that depend on identifying connections.  Maybe a network engineer reading this could weigh in on the topic?  In any case, it's an interesting problem and study and I hope you get it worked out to your satisfaction.

Comment: @BrandonXavier Yes I tested my current incomplete solution on the internet, to confound the greatest firewall all over the world...... Which has a mechanism to detect connections between ip:port pairs, and may shutdown connection and block remote ip:port when anything suspicious detected. My current solution can avoid inaccessibility of the remote server, but I have to reconnect when existing one get blocked. Sure reconnection does work because remote port is changed. LBs and routers are not my concern as there is only 1 remote server, and changing port shouldn't affect routers.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking something that goes against the very same philosophy of the IP port system, contrack, etc etc. You won't be able to do what you want with iptables.

Can you imagine if you have 2 different processes in your client trying to establish this kind of traffic with the server? of course it would be a mess.

If you need to make your traffic difficult to trace or anything like that I would recommend you to think of different alternatives but always based on non disruptive IP traffic.

Comment: A server listens on 10000 ports at same time, or any kind of iptables-based reversed-proxy/load-balancer, are they "disruption"? If they are not, I don't see why changing port of UDP packets can be so evil.
The box has a single purpose to act as a VPN gateway, just like you will never run 2 DHCP servers on your WIFI router, there will never be 2 clients running at same time. Why this can be a problem?
Anyway I'm working on a iptables extension module which simply changes UPD port to a random number, some preliminary tests passed, and I'll post my code here when it's fully functional.

Comment: 1) I think your logic is flawed. 2)The disruption is not about how many ports a server is listening to. The disruption is using random port change for every sent packet on the same process/communication.

Comment: Communicate without connection established, isn't it the very purpose of UDP? Why it's wrong to use different port for every packet?

Answer (score 0):

As setting a test environment for your case would be quite a hassle, this answer isn't tested enough. Use on your own responsibility.

I can think of these solutions:

1. Create a daemon-like script, constantly updating your client-side iptables rule, changing ports range a few times every second.
2. Like 1., but reset UDP states table using `conntrack -D -p udp --dst $DEST_IP` from [conntrack-tools](http://conntrack-tools.netfilter.org/).
3. Play with as-low-as-possible values in */proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_udp_timeout* or, probably better, */proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_udp_timeout_stream*.

To me, **option 2.** seems the least harmful to the performance and general connectivity. Option 1. may AFAIK not work as expected without 3.

Comment: Tried all but none worked, as I guessed.
1st doesn't work because of newly created iptables rules may have no effect on established "connections".
2nd doesn't work as DNAT randomization seems to be one shot on the first packet, and not be re-done even I flushed whole connection state table with `conntrack -F`.
3rd is the idle timeout of established connections but in my case, the connection is kinda busy.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, but since you only need to change the destination port, and not an IP address, have you tried to use REDIRECT instead of DNAT also for output chain?

E.g., `iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT --dst server.ip.addr -p udp --dport 3333 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 10000-19999 --random`

EDIT:

You problem should be on the client side. I tried to reproduce your case using ncat (and without client side iptables rules):

Server side iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --dst 192.168.5.129 -p udp --match multiport --dport 10000:19999 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3333
iptables -A FORWARD -m state -p udp -d 192.168.5.129 --dport 3333 --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

server side ncat:

```
ncat -ul 3333
```

client side ncats:

```
ncat -p 3333 -u 192.168.5.129 10004
ncat -p 3333 -u 192.168.5.129 10003
```

Using this setup, redirect on the server side works. I believe, the problem is in the "--random" option for iptables, which probably means that DNAT randomises port mapping for the connection, not for single packet.

Another problem for you could be an optional 'source port' field in the UDP header. If it is set, probably the firewall still will be able to track your connection.

Comment: No it doesn't work, REDIRECT target does *not* only change port, it also redirects traffic to *local* machine by changing the dest ip to something like 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Ok, I was wrong. I'm currently trying to reproduce this scenario using netcat and ncat. I started with port redirect on server only, but somehow netcat does not accept messages from second netcat client, if first is "connected". I assume that the problem is that netcat probably checks UDP source port.

Comment: Also, man iptables says "If  option --random is used then port mapping will be randomized", which probably means that it is randomised for the connection, not for single packet.

Comment: Yes, `--random` is for the connection not single packet, that's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: One more question to this `--random`. Will this redirection be **aware** of that a port that it has "sampled" is already used by some running application (it did `bind()` to that port), use another port if so, and always drop packets if all of the ports from the range are busy?